# Converting String to Json Properly from the Dictionary

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, unity-game-engine, unitywebrequest

I would like to send a json request to a flask server. I use `UnityWebRequest` to do so as following,

```
IEnumerator Post(string url, string bodyJsonString)
{
    var request = new UnityWebRequest(url, "POST");
    byte[] bodyRaw = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bodyJsonString);
    request.uploadHandler = (UploadHandler) new UploadHandlerRaw(bodyRaw);
    request.downloadHandler = (DownloadHandler) new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
    request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    yield return request.SendWebRequest();
}
```

I use the following code to create the json,

```
Dictionary<string, string> RootJson = new Dictionary<string, string>();
Dictionary<string, float> id_val = new Dictionary<string, float>();
Dictionary<string,byte[]> employeeData = new Dictionary<string, byte[]>();

CalibrationJson.Add("id",1);
imagesJson.Add("employeeData",encodedByte);

RootJson.Add("id", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(id_val.ToString()));
RootJson.Add("data", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employeeData.ToString()));

StartCoroutine(Post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/emp_detail", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(RootJson.ToString())));
```

However it is not creating a proper json though I have serialized the dictionary everytime. It throws the following error in the server,

> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `ToString` from your serialization code:

```
RootJson.Add("id", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(id_val));
RootJson.Add("data", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employeeData));

StartCoroutine(Post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/emp_detail", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(RootJson)));
```

For types which do not override `ToString` it will return the type name, so for  `Dictionary<string, string>()` you will get *"System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]"*:

```
Console.WriteLine(new Dictionary<string, string>().ToString()); // prints System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]
```